# pythonic for loop to write excel formulas with different variables

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Sorry for the unclear title - I wasn't sure how to best word this.

I have a bit of code which is going to populate a new column in my dataframe and subsequently Excel. I'm attempting to add two cells in the same row (columns E, F) but also the rightmost (column H) cell from the previous row and I don't think I've structured my code efficiently or correctly.

`len_newf` is the length of the dataframe, `newf`, but has been changed to a random integer for ease of reproduction.

Current working code is:

```
len_newf = 8
lform = []

x = 0
y = 1
z = 1

for i, j, k in zip(range(x, len_newf+2), range(y, len_newf+2),range(z,len_newf+2)):

    formula = '=(H{0}+E{1}+F{1})'.format(i,j,k)
    lform.append(formula)
```

Output:

```
['=(H0+E1+F1)', '=(H1+E2+F2)', '=(H2+E3+F3)', '=(H3+E4+F4)', '=(H4+E5+F5)', '=(H5+E6+F6)', '=(H6+E7+F7)', '=(H7+E8+F8)', '=(H8+E9+F9)']
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What is your question? Where is the dataframe? Show an example input with an expected output.

Comment: Any arbitrary number could be used for the length. I've added output. My question is what is wrong with my code in terms of good practice. The output is correct but I don't think I'm doing it in the best way.

Comment: I don't see any problem with this code. You might want to look at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for help in how to make it more efficient.